# Calculating Jacobian matrix for state space model and measurement model in extended kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am using constant velocity model to estimate the position in Kalman filter. The measurements are generated from simulation in Matlab using randn function which will be added to ground truth data which is also generated on Matlab. And since its radar measurement which will be having basically the angle and range. In order to calculate position in Cartesian coordinate system I am using sin and cos functions which obviously in non-linear. With simple Kalman filter i see my corrections are almost following the measurement. So I am planning to move to extended kalman filter. Since the state space model is still linear but the measurements are non linear(because of sin and cos) . Should I just get Jacobian of measurement matrix ? I saw similar implementation in one of Github pages(https://github.com/mithi/fusion-ekf-python). But I am not sure how is Jacobian calculated there and code snippet looks like this

```
r11 = px / d
r12 = py / d
r21 = -py / d_squared
r22 = px / d_squared
r31 = py * (vx * py - vy * px) / d_cubed
r32 = px * (vy * px - vx * py) / d_cubed

H = np.matrix([[r11, r12, 0, 0], 
              [r21, r22, 0, 0], 
              [r31, r32, r11, r12]])
```

where px ,py are positions and vx and vy are velocities in x and y axis.

Can anyone please let me know how is Jacobian calculated here and is it fine if I just use Jacobian for measurement matrix H which is used in Kalman Gain calculation using KG= PH(transpose)/HPH(transpose) equation

Thank you

Bheeshma

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the example you give is range, bearing and radial velocity. Since you want just range and bearing, you should throw away the third row.

One issue is: what are the units of the observations? I'll suppose that the range (like the position states) are in metres and the range is in radians. Changing these is straightforward: if for example your bearings are in degrees, you should multiply everything to do with a bearing below (the computed value, the components of its derivatives) by 180/pi.

A slightly more subtle issue is: what is the sense of the bearings? That is, are they measured counter-clockwise from the x axis (as is usual in mathematics), or clockwise from the y axis (which if we think of the y axis as north and the x axis as east is usual in navigation).

I'll use the navigation convention here, and use as states the position (n,e) of the target, given as how far north (n) and east (e) it is from the radar sensor, and also its velocity (u,v) (u north, v east). However the measurements depend only on n and e, so there'll be no more mention of u or v.

A final issue is: are the targets far enough away from the sensor that we should not, as above, be using a flat earth model? I'll assume that we can ignore earth curvature.

Our measurements, in terms of the position states are then

```
range = sqrt( e*e + n*n)
brng = atan2( e, n)
```

We also need the Jacobian, that is the derivatives of each of range and brng with respect to both n and e. (Well actually we want the derivatives wrt u and v as well, but these are 9 for both range and bearing). So we want

```
drangebydn
drangebyde
dbrngbydn
dbrngbyde
```

There are various ways of going about this. One is to do the differentiations by hand and code up the results; another is to use 'automatic differentiation' (if the implementation language supports it); a last resort is to try to do it numerically.

Here's my attempt (untested) at doing them by hand:
The equation for the range is easy enough but the atan2 is a bit trickier. Usually maths books just talk about atan, not quite the same thing. One way to do the calculations in this case is to consider instead the inverse problem: in terms of r and b we have

```
n = r*cos(b)
e = r*sin(b)
```

These are easy to differentiate, and I get the Jacobian of r,b->n,e as

```
( n/r  -e )
( e/r  n  )
```

We want the Jacobian of n,e -> r,b; this is the inverse of the matrix above. So finally:

```
Let r = range(n,e)
drangebydn = n/r 
drangebyde = e/r 
dbrngbydn = -e/(r*r) 
drangebyde = n/(r*r)
```

I've done this sort of thing quite a lot and (as a result of wasting a lot of time, and losing a lot of hair) I always test the derivatives separately. Filters and estimators that use derivatives are hard to debug; you'll save yourself time and heartache by always testing the bits separately. A simple test, that catches a lot of common errors, is to use, if we have a function f (for example range(n,e) for fixed e) and its derivative fdot (for example drangebydn), that the integral of fdot over an interval n0,n1 is the difference f(n1)-f(n0). One can do the integral numerically.